# How to use redux to maintain state with an application that has copies of sub-applications (tabs) - while still allowing access to a global state

Tags: redux, react-redux

**Background**

I'm creating an application for querying a database connection. Each connection can have multiple tabs each with an isolated state containing the query, custom options and eventually the database results. The complexity of each sub-app or tab is pretty high, so I initially thought of isolating my sub-apps per the redux documentation: https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps

However, the issue I ran into was that there was no way I could access my "global" state (the database connection in my case.)

Since that didn't work, I then tried to initialize a separate redux instance using React hooks. Which works, but doesn't actually keep my application stored once the user navigates to other parts of the app and intends to return to their previous state.

**Question**

What is the best practice for managing isolated redux state containers that can also reference a global state? I know this a little high level, happy to elaborate on details/sample code if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> redux state containers that can also reference a global state?

If you need access to global state, then I would just stick with the Redux reducer composition.

Comment: Currently using a hybrid of Redux for my global state + Hooks for isolated redux containers. The main issue that each "isolated container" has multiple reducers and sagas. So trying to maintain all those things in a single global array property doesn't seem scalable.

Comment: Why is it not scalable?

Comment: Say I have `ApplicationState` with a property called `queryTabs: []` and each array item is a simple state for queryString and results. Querying for each result is handled with sagas, so I can cancel mid-query also handle returning additional results since this particular database (Salesforce) only allows me to retieve 200 records at a time.

Comment: With a single property, all these actions would have to exist in one reducer, action and saga. Now I need to add other stateful features: filtering, pagination, query configurations, database manipulations (update/delete). Quickly this is getting out of hand.

Comment: What I want is to build these features into separate reducers, actions, sagas, and types that provides a nice clean separation of concerns (Which I am currently doing). I don't see how it's possible to move these things to a global state as an array and maintain that separation

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this problem by normalizing the structure of my state: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/

After flattening the data structure, my new state looks like this:

```
export interface QueryTabsState {
  readonly byId:  { [key: string]: QueryTabState }
  readonly allIds : string[]
  readonly activeId?: string
}

export interface QueryTabState {
  readonly id: string
  readonly title: string
}

export interface QueryState {
  readonly tabId: string
  readonly query: any
  readonly searchFilter: string
  readonly includeDeleted: boolean
  readonly toolingMode: boolean
  readonly errors?: any
  readonly paginationConfig: PaginationConfig
  readonly parsedQuery?: any
  readonly batchSize: number
}

export interface QueryResultState {
  readonly tabId: string
  readonly data: any
  readonly filteredIds: string[]
  readonly selectedIds: string[]
  readonly totalSize: any
  readonly pending: boolean
  readonly dmlPending: boolean
  readonly errors?: any
}
```

Now when switching tabs, I can look for changes to activeId and then fetch each individual component's independently. Helped simplify this quite a bit.